# Anyone know this science fiction story about a sentient space suit?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, space-exploration

Does anyone know the title or author of a story where a lone spaceman is walking across lunar surface in a suit that has sentience. The story skilfully teases the reader into believing the spaceman is still alive, but when it is found the suit contains a skeleton.

Comment: There is a similar story line in "[Have Space Suit—Will Travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Space_Suit%E2%80%94Will_Travel)", by Robert A. Heinlein.

Answer (score 35):

This is Iain M Banks' short story *Descendant*, published in his collection *The State of the Art*.

Comment: A nice yarn, and one that illuminates some details of the way the Culture deals with the moral questions concerning borderline sentient AIs; a topic not discussed in other stories that I am aware of.

Comment: @dhof, if this is the correct answer, can you click the check mark to mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: I hurt. Good read.